# Installing node with apt-get or downloading the Linux Binaries (.tar.gz)

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, nodejs

What is the difference between installing node.js with 'sudo apt-get install nodejs' or downloading the Linux Binaries (.tar.gz) and following [these](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/04/19/how-to-install-getting-started-with-node-js-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-linux-easy-guide/) instructions?

Is the outcome the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing from source has one pitfall, that removing (and otherwise keeping track of installed files) becomes difficult. It's best to let the package manager handle the installation. You can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js) and then `apt-get` will get you the latest version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

---

The PPA has since been moved to [another source](https://deb.nodesource.com). The instructions from the [NodeJS Github wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The commands, condensed out from the script:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release curl 
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node $(lsb_release -sc) main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node $(lsb_release -sc) main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.04/zesty currently.

Comment: @digitaldonkey https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions doesn't list 17.04 a supported release.

Comment: That is what I intended to add :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences

- The version available for Ubuntu is made for Ubuntu, and will include/depend on any extra packages needed, and may have specific configuration for Ubuntu
- The version for Ubuntu can just be installed using apt - the tar.gz from the nodejs will need to be configured.
- The version from the nodejs site will be more up-to-date *(currently [v0.10.30 on their site](http://nodejs.org/download/) compared to [v0.10.25 from the Ubuntu repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nodejs))*

Note you can use a PPA to get a more up-to-date version - e.g. [this one](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js).

Comment: well..the binaries don't need to be compiled

Comment: Are saying that Linux Binaries (.tar.gz) is not made for ubuntu?
p.s. your post was useful, even if it was somewhat comfusing. So I want to up rate it but I don't have enough points to do so :(
p.p.s I just got enough points to up vote your answer :)

Comment: The linux binaries should work on most Linux systems - including Ubuntu. It just the version from the ubuntu repos might have modifications so it works better with Ubuntu.